# Calling Invalidate from MainActivity doesn't execute OnDraw

Tags: android, kotlin, android-view

So i tried out kotlin in android and wanted to begin with painting a circle on a view, where i get a touch input. It worked fine, when i had the onTouchEvent in the View-Class, but i wanted to put the logic outside of the graphic part, so i made a method in the view class, which changes the coordinates of the circle and calls invalidate(). Now i put the onTouchEvent in to the MainActivity and called the method with the new coordinates. The methods gets called as i can see by system.out.println(), but invalidate() doesn't calls on Draw() so the circle doesn't change. I think there is a simple solution for that problem, but i can't find it. So i would be very happy to get some help.

Here's my code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
      setContentView(GameView(this))


    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent?): Boolean {

      GameView(this).updateCircle(event!!.x,event!!.y)
      return true
    }

}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
class GameView(context: Context): View(context) {

  val paint : Paint
  var circleX : Float
  var circleY : Float


  init {
      paint = Paint();
      paint.isFilterBitmap = true;
      paint.isAntiAlias = true;
      paint.color = Color.YELLOW;
      circleX = 100f;
      circleY = 100f;

  }

  override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
      System.out.println("Gets Called")
      super.onDraw(canvas)
      canvas?.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
      canvas?.drawCircle(circleX,circleY,50f,paint)
  }



  fun drawGrid(height: Int,width: Int){

  }

  fun updateCircle(x:Float,y:Float){

      circleX = x
      circleY = y          
      invalidate()
      System.out.println(circleX)
  }

}
```

GameView.kt

Comment: The `GameView` instance you've set as the `Activity`'s content is not the same as in `onTouchEvent()`. In that method, for every event, you're creating a new instance, calling your method on it, and then it's discarded. You want to keep reference to the one you call `setContentView()` with.

Comment: where should i create the reference because, i can't do it in the init part either in onCreate

Comment: You need to declare it as a field, outside of a any class method. I'm not very familiar with Kotlin yet, but I think it would be something like `var gameView: GameView? = null`. Then assign that in `onCreate()`, and call `setContentView()` with it.

Comment: That was the solution thanks for your help